# COUNT field with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

If i had a table such as

```
 Name       Email
 Sam      s@hot.com
 Fred     f@hot.com
 Ben        Null
 Tom        Null
```

And i want to count how many people don't have an email

so i thought

```
 SELECT 
 Name,
 Email,
 CASE WHEN Email IS NULL
 THEN COUNT(Email) ELSE 0 END AS [Count]
 FROM Table1
 Group by Name,Email
```

But the result i get is

```
 Name       Email     Count
 Sam      s@hot.com     0
 Fred     f@hot.com     0
 Ben        Null        0
 Tom        Null        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(name) from Table1 where email is null
```

or if you need to count number of distinct names:

```
select count(distinct name) from Table1 where email is null
```

Answer (score 1):

For counting how many people don't have an email, you don't need a `group by` clause - you're just trying to get a single answer:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   table1
WHERE  email IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT()` will ignore `NULL` fields.  The wording in your question also indicates that you only want the total count of all people without an email, so the `GROUP BY` doesn't seem necessary.

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
Select   Count(*)
From     Table1
Where    Email Is Null;
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a field that has 1 or 0 when there is no email, you are close.

```
SELECT Name, Email, NoEmail = CASE WHEN Email IS NULL OR Email = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Table1;
```

Alternately just count how many WHEN Email IS NULL.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
WHERE Email IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 
 count(name)
 FROM Table1
where email is null
```

Comment: i don't think this answers the question.